# What a single mode optical resonator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, cavity-qed

This is a term from cavity quantum electrodynamics. I want to know whether the wavelength can be different when the mode is on: one of $d$ , $d/2$, ...., $d/n$ or is it always equal to $d$. 
Also how is this mode practically achieved?

Comment: I'm confused by this. The question in the title is relatively benign. But the question in the body text is less clear and separate from the title question. We can describe what a single-mode optical resonator is, but are you asking if such a thing is possible? Are you asking if other frequencies can be present in the resonator? Can you clarify your main question?

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing exactly what you read, and what you are getting at.  It's possible that the development chooses to ignore all modes except one for simplicity.  Or the discussion could be about a laser, in which case the meaning is entirely different.   But a mode has one frequency.   Modes beyond the fundamental will have different frequencies, and ... are different modes.

Comment: @Jim The optical resonator is in fact (mainly) the 
Fabri -Perault - two mirrors parallel on distance d. The WL of the EM wave within can be any multiple lambda = d/n n=1, ... Of course as it is single mode - WL is only one. But must it be lambda =d or can be any d/n? e.g the lowest frequency or any other higher one.

Comment: @garyp - I'm reading: Single photon simultaneously excites two atoms = Savasta et.al http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00886

Comment: It sounds like he is focusing on one mode.  As you say, many modes exist in an average-sized resonator, but they are being ignored.  It's possible that he is imagining the fundamental mode of a very short resonator.   In such a case the next higher mode would be  far away in the ultraviolet.  I took a *quick* look at the paper, and I don't see where he makes clear what he means.  I'm *guessing* that his analysis doesn't care what kind of mode it is.  I think, but I'm far from sure, that he simply wants to consider only one mode.